# How to mass-fetch pages from a website behind authentication in PHP

Tags: php, http, authentication, curl, fetch

Yes, yes, i know user and password.

I need some trick in php to get logged into a website and retrieve some images/contents, like a normal website.

Obviously with a curl o file_get_contents it doesn't work because i'm not authenticated.

How i can do?

The authentication is normal HTTP auth with POST.

**Edit**: ok thanks for help it works!

I post working code here for future reference

```
//login and set cookie
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookiefile");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookiefile"); # SAME cookiefile
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "url in which there is the login form"); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "user=test&password=test&someparam=somevalue"); //put here the post/get values
$output = curl_exec($curl);

echo $output;

//finally fetch my content
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url_to_fetch); 
$output = curl_exec($curl);
echo $output;

curl_close ($curl);
```

Comment: Do you need to do this programmatically using PHP.  If not, try using wget or the like.  What sort of authentication does the website use?  An HTML form or HTTP basic authentication, or something more exotic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can authenticate with curl.  Curl allows for sending POST variables to login, and also basic HTTP authentication.

Comment: if i do so, how can i keep in session authentication success and call curl to other pages?

Answer (score 1):

Use the browser to authenticate yourself, export the cookies and use them via curl. 
Until the session lasts you should impersonate your user.

I'm in a hurry and can't provide you code just now, but I think this directions can help you

You can use the CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE option to specify the file in which you stored the cookies.

As stated in the [php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

```
The name of the file containing the cookie data. 
The cookie file can be in Netscape format, or just 
plain HTTP-style headers dumped into a file.
```